# Syntax highlighting for embedded languages in VS Code

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

I am busy making my own grammar extension in Visual Studio Code. The language is called Snake, say, and the grammar kicks in when a file of the kind "*.snk" is opened, for instance "hello-world.snk". So far, so good. I can teach VS Code the syntax highlighting for Snake in a grammar file, and it all works.

But I can't get embedded language *syntax highlighting* to work.

Inside a ".snk" file, it is possible to include javascript codeblocks. I am able to get VS Code to give *programmatic language support*  for javascript (like snippets) inside these embedded javascript codeblocks to work (via the `embeddedLanguages` property in the `tmLanguage.json` file). But I can't get javascript *syntax highlighting* to work inside the javascript codeblocks.

In fact, the [documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/syntax-highlight-guide#embedded-languages) is entirely silent on getting *syntax highlighting* for embedded languages to work. It only talks about programmatic features  like commenting code and triggering snippets.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 6):

in packages.json

```js
     "embeddedLanguages": {
                    "source.js": "javascript",
                    "meta.embedded.block.javascript": "javascript"
      }
```

in your syntax def file:

```json
 "jscode": {
            "patterns": [
                {
                    "name": "js.block.sl",
                    "begin": "js:\\s*{{{",
                    "end": "^\\s*}}}\\s*$",
                    "patterns": [
                        {
                            "begin": "(^|\\G)(\\s*)(.*)",
                            "end": "^\\s*}}}\\s*$",
                            "contentName": "meta.embedded.block.javascript",
                            "patterns": [
                                {
                                    "include": "source.js"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
```

Adjust the begin and end pattern.

in short, you need match the begin and end of your block. then in the matched block, match js and include all js highlight pattern.

How I learn this ? from vscode source code.

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/master/extensions/markdown-basics/package.json

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/master/extensions/markdown-basics/syntaxes/markdown.tmLanguage.json#L959

Comment: Doesn't using the 'include' there actually burn in the source.js, rather than using the embeddedLanguages at all? Kinda feels it should be one or the other?

Answer (score 2):

I was looking for something similar and here's what struck me.

This is a sample pattern from the `.tmLanguage.json` for my language "mylang". It's for strings, that begin with a `'` or `"` and end with the same character. Within the string, there are escape characters coloured differently, and because "mylang" supports string interpolation, you can have stuff like `"value is $value"`, where the variable references should be coloured differently (compared to the overall string colour).

This *is* basic embedded highlighting, and if you have clear anchors that mark the start and end of your embedded language snippet, you can adjust the `begin` and `end` and it should work.

```
"strings": {
            "name": "string.quoted.double.mylang",
            "begin": "(\"|')",
            "end": "\\1",
            "patterns": [
                {
                    "name": "constant.character.escape.mylang",
                    "match": "\\{[a-z.0-9,A-Z*_/~-]*\\}|\\\\|\\\\0\\d\\d|\\\\\\w"
                },
                {
                    "name": "variable.name.mylang",
                    "match": "\\$[a-z][a-z.0-9A-Z]*|\\$\\([a-z.0-9,A-Z-]*\\)(\\([.0-9-]+\\))?"
                }
            ]
        }
```

Now if I were to define a new object in my code, say, using the following syntax:

```
var mjs = JSON('{"value": 42}')
```

`var` is a language keyword, `JSON` is a class/type name. The `JSON` constructor takes a string containing the JSON text, and parses it to a tree.

They have their own highlight colours. The string within `''` has its own overall colour. I would now want everything between the regexes `JSON\\('` and `'\\)` to be coloured based on various sub-patterns (e.g. keys might be `".*"\s+:` and so on)

Note that if I literally specified `JSON\\(` as the begin pattern, the `JSON` would be part of it, and not be highlighted with the colour for type names. It might help to use a lookbehind instead: `(?<JSON)\\(` if memory serves right.

And repeat the whole thing for `YAML('...')`, `XML('...')`, ...